# Calling function from Worksheet_Change with custom object as parameter

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, custom-object, vba

Code below is giving me an `Object doesn't support this property or method` in `HelperFunctions.updatecontractlist (PC)`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PCName As String, BU, PC As Variant
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        PCName = Target.value
        For Each BU In TotalBook.GetBUs
            For Each PC In BU.GetPCs
                If PC.Name = PCName Then HelperFunctions.updatecontractlist (PC)
        Next PC, BU
    End If
End Sub
```

where `updatecontractlist` is:

```
Public Sub updatecontractlist(PC As Variant)

 whatever

End Sub
```

and `PC` is custom object what works fine in many other parts of the code and I can see, in my `Watches` window, that it's properly loaded when the bug happens.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

`If PC.Name = PCName Then HelperFunctions.updatecontractlist (PC)`

to

`If PC.Name = PCName Then Call HelperFunctions.updatecontractlist (PC)`

or

`If PC.Name = PCName Then HelperFunctions.updatecontractlist PC`